# Starting ASP.NET Core from Visual Studio doesn't start from build folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, appsettings, slowcheetah

When you start an ASP.NET Core project from Visual Studio (2017) it assumes the working directory is where the source code is located, not where the built files are actually placed.

Which means that when I run my project it reads the config file from `C:\Path\To\My\Project\appsettings.json`, and not from `C:\Path\To\My\Project\bin\Debug\appsettings.json`.

I can see that this is the case when I debug this code:

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) => {
        config.SetBasePath(context.HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath);
        config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, false);
    });
```

Where `ContentRootPath` points to the project folder, not where the built files are placed.

I could probably fix this by setting the `Working Directory` in `Project Properties > Debug`, but seeing as we're also using configuration transforms (SlowCheetah), each developer will have their own build configuration for debug output (`bin\Debug[CustomConfiguration]`), and changing `.csproj` for one developer breaks it for all the other developers.

Is there any way of having ASP.NET Core read the config files from where the built files are placed instead of the project folder, without having to change the `Working Directory`, yet still working for multiple "Build Configurations"?

Comment: That's how Microsoft designed it, https://blog.lextudio.com/how-visual-studio-launches-iis-express-to-debug-asp-net-core-apps-d7fd3677e3c3

Comment: @LexLi Yes, obviously. How can I circumvent this so that SlowCheetah transforms are used?

Comment: Let SlowCheetah developers change their code to adapt to such a design.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly, every developer has a different output folder with respect to their username. So, if you make up something like this,

```
        var debug = string.Empty;
        #if DEBUG
            debug = "Debug";
        #else
            debug = "Release";
        #endif

        var userNameVariable = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USER");
        debug += $"[{userNameVariable}]";

        var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "bin", debug);
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(path) //env.ContentRootPath
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

I have tested this on Mac OS and result is

```
/Users/johndoe/Documents/Temp/contentasp/bin/Debug[johndoe]
```

**Other solution.**

In visual studio you have pre-build and post-build scripts. In Visual Studio you can get the OutputFolder and set the path into a environment variable on pre-build script. For example:

`powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "$(ProjectDir)outputscript.ps1" -OutputFolder $(OutputPath)`

And in the powershell script (`outputscript.ps1`)

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
        [string]$OutputFolder
)

$env:OutputFolder = $OutputFolder
```

And you can get the value on the startup with

```
var outputFolder = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("OutputFolder");
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(outputFolder) //env.ContentRootPath
```

Comment: There's not really a username, just different build configurations with a naming standard: `Debug[initials of user]`, so creating all that code for a development environment seems a bit excessive

Comment: The other solution is, if you can set the output folder path into a environment variable on pre-build script. You can get that from `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("OutputFolder")` and set into SetBasePath. I don't think there exist a native solution for this, you have to improvise.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help is set to directory as application working directory by:

```
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(context.HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath);
```

Comment: `context.HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath` points to `C:\Path\To\My\Project`, whereas I want to run from `C:\Path\To\My\Project\bin\debug[User]` (because that's where the transformed appsettings.json file is placed)

Comment: set to copy it to bin directory in .csproj ?                                                         
<None Include="appsettings.json" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" />

Comment: The `appsettings.json` is already copied to the `bin` directory. The problem is that when doing `Debug > Start Debugging` in Visual Studio, it doesn't start from the `bin` directory, but from the project directory, so it doesn't find the transformed file.

Answer (score 0):

Config files are read from the place that you configure via `SetBasePath`. What happens in Development mode is that when you use `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder` it sets `BasePath` to source code folder which is logical for most developer cases.

It actually does not work out of the box for Console applications e.g., so I specifically do the same in there.

There are probably few ways you can fix this:

1. Using the existing system as it is quite convenient by default. Perhaps you can explain in more details why does it not work for you?
2. Not using `CreateDefaultBuilder` and creating the builder yourself, then you'll be able to configure it exactly as you want.
3. Override `SetBasePath` with the value you want afterwards. I assume that e.g. `AppContext.BaseDirectory` or `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` will return the path that you are looking for
4. Not using name "Development" for your environment will probably do the trick as well, though you will have some other consequences that you need to consider.

P.S. Why would you use slowcheetah at all to do the old styled transformation when you can use agile config? You can read config from multiple files and the last one in order always win, so it will be the same effect as from using slowcheetah in practice.